# Analytical charts in Fiori v/s CDS

Tags: sap-fiori, cds

I am trying to create analytical charts in SAP. I have read that we can create analytical charts in Fiori and CDS views. Which of the two would be a better approach?

Comment: "I am trying to create ... in SAP" (What is "SAP" in your context? SAP is a company), "I have read" (where??), "create [...] charts in Fiori" (SAP Fiori is the name of their UX design language. What do you mean by "Fiori"??). --> The question is too unclear to answer. Please specify the landscape of your tech stack. Which product are you exactly using? In which version?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you write: "… Which of the two would be a better approach?"

There might be a misunderstanding and simply put:
With CDS views you retrieve the data from the backend and with Fiori you display these data at the frontend.

These blogs might be helpful for understanding the concept:

[ABAP CDS Views and Reporting Tools](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/12/abap-cds-views-reporting-tools/)

[Smart charts in a SAP Fiori Object Page using ABAP CDS views and annotations](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/11/27/smart-charts-in-object-pages-using-abap-cds-annotations/)

[Create an Analytical List Page using ABAP CDS views and annotations](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/04/create-an-analytical-list-page-using-abap-cds-views-and-annotations/)

For displaying charts, you might also want to look into [the official docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame).